# Nginx reverse proxy multiple applications on single tomcat instance

Tags: tomcat, nginx, proxy

I am trying to get nginx to reverse proxy multiple applications on a tomcat server from different *server_names*. For example client `a` would be sent to their application on tomcat at `app-a`.

Instead the behavior is that the browser does not receive js files nor images or css. Its just gets the HTML.

```
user  www-data;

        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
        pid        /run/nginx.pid;

        worker_processes  2;

        events {
            worker_connections  1024;
            multi_accept on;
        }

        http {
              client_body_buffer_size 10m;
              client_header_buffer_size 1m;
              client_max_body_size 20m;
              large_client_header_buffers 2 1m;

              keepalive_timeout 300s;
              send_timeout 300s;

              proxy_http_version 1.1;
              proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
              proxy_send_timeout 300s;
              proxy_read_timeout 300s;

              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_bind $server_addr;

              proxy_buffering off;
              chunked_transfer_encoding off;

              # kill cache
              #add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
              #add_header Cache-Control 'private no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
              if_modified_since off;
              expires off;
              etag off;

              # kill proxy cache, even if cached, don't try to use it
              proxy_no_cache 1;
              proxy_cache_bypass 1;

              server {
                    listen 80;
                    listen [::]:80;

                    server_name ~^([\w\d-]+)\.app\.uat\.us\.pic\.com;

                    location / {
                         proxy_pass http://uat-client-appservers.us.pic.com:80/app-$1/;
                    }
                    location /app/ {
                          proxy_pass http://uat-client-appservers.us.pic.com:80/app-$1/;
                    }
                    location /app-handler/ {
                          proxy_pass http://uat-client-appservers.us.pic.com:80/app-handler-$1/;
                    }
              }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a separate server context for each client application and using a redirect to handle routing from the root context.

user  www-data;

```
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    pid        /run/nginx.pid;

    worker_processes  2;

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
        multi_accept on;
    }

    http {
          client_body_buffer_size 10m;
          client_header_buffer_size 1m;
          client_max_body_size 20m;
          large_client_header_buffers 2 1m;

          keepalive_timeout 300s;
          send_timeout 300s;

          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
          proxy_send_timeout 300s;
          proxy_read_timeout 300s;

          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_bind $server_addr;

          proxy_buffering off;
          chunked_transfer_encoding off;

          # kill cache
          #add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
          #add_header Cache-Control 'private no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
          #if_modified_since off;
          #expires off;
          #etag off;

          # kill proxy cache, even if cached, don't try to use it
          proxy_no_cache 1;
          proxy_cache_bypass 1;

          server {
                listen 80;
                listen [::]:80;

                server_name a.app.uat.us.pic.com;

                location = / {
                     return http://a.app.uat.us.pic.com/app-a/;
                }
                location /app/ {
                      proxy_pass http://uat-client-appservers.us.pic.com:80/app-a/;
                }
                location /app-handler/ {
                      proxy_pass http://uat-client-appservers.us.pic.com:80/app-handler-a/;
                }
          }
    }
```